# Problem with exit and enter animations using react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css, react-transition-group

I'm new to React and I'm looking for some help.

I'm trying to build a simple login page. The page gives users three options ('sign in with email', 'sign in with Google', or 'sign up') and displays a component based on the option chosen.

I wanted to add a simple cross-fade as these components enter and exit the DOM so I turned to react-transition-group.

The problem, however, is my components don't exit and enter properly. The old component appears to disappear instantly rather than fade out, two copies of the 'new' component are stacked on top of each other. One fades out and the other fades in. The old and new don't elegantly cross-fade into each other as I would like.

Example:

[Initial login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTOCU.png)

[On click, two copies of the 'new' component appear, one fades in and the other fades out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoycR.png)

[transition completes and container now holds the new component as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw1aa.png)

I've looked over [the docs](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) for react-transition-group but I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my main component:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: "loginInitial"
        }
    };

    handleEmailLogin = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            display: "emailLogin"
        }))     
    };

    handleGoogleLogin = () => {
        console.log("Logging in with google!")
        this.props.startGoogleLogin()
    };

    handleEmailSignUp= () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            display: "emailSignUp"
        }))     
    };

    handleBackToStart = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            display: "loginInitial",
        }))     
    }

    displayBox = () => {
        if (this.state.display === "loginInitial") {
            return <LoginPageInitial
                handleEmailLogin={this.handleEmailLogin}
                handleGoogleLogin={this.handleGoogleLogin}
                handleEmailSignUp={this.handleEmailSignUp}
                />
        } else if (this.state.display === "emailSignUp") {
            return <LoginPageEmailSignUp
                handleBackToStart={this.handleBackToStart}
                    />
        } else if (this.state.display === "emailLogin") {
            return <LoginPageEmailLogin
                handleBackToStart={this.handleBackToStart}
                    />
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box-layout">
            <div className="box-layout__box">
                <h1 className="box-layout__title">My app</h1>
                <p>Subtitle goes here blah blah blah blah.</p>
                    <TransitionGroup>
                            <CSSTransition
                                classNames="fade"
                                timeout={600}
                                key={this.state.display}
                            >
                            {this.displayBox}
                            </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startGoogleLogin: () => dispatch(startGoogleLogin())
})

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage)
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
.box-layout {
    align-items: center;
    background: url('/images/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.box-layout__box {
    background: fade-out(white,.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30rem;
    padding: $l-size $m-size
}

.box-layout__title {
    margin: 0 0  $m-size 0;
    line-height: 1;
}

// FADE
// appear
.fade-appear {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fade-appear.fade-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 600ms linear;
}

// enter
.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 600ms linear;    
}

// exit
.fade-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-exit.fade-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 600ms linear;    
}
```

I would be ***extremely*** appreciative if anyone can offer some advice. I've done a lot of googling but I can't find a solution to my problem.

[**EDIT:** MOSTLY SOLVED - I managed to solve the bulk of my problem. It appears I needed to place my 'key' prop in my  component rather than  component. Two versions of the 'new' component no longer appear and the container doesn't stretch. It does appear, however, that the 'old' component still doesn't fade out as I expected. It looks a lot better than it did though. I welcome any further insight on what I was/am doing wrong or how I can improve my code.)

Comment: You did not set a prefered height inside your css, maybe setting one is the answer your looking for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Fabien. I should have mentioned that I've tried setting my container div (box-layout__box) to a fixed height and I've also tried adding a class to <TransitionGroup> and with a fixed height. Unfortunately, neither action corrected the problem. Instead of stretching the div, the old component was simply bumped outside of the boundaries of the container as the new component entered.

Comment: A quick update: I realized my problem was a bit more nuanced than just my container being stretched. After slowing down the animation, I realized that my div is being stretched by two versions of the same component (one performing the exit animation, the other performing the enter animation). I've updated this question accordingly.